# Ghost featured image and iframe issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ghost

HTML

```
<div class="blog-post">
  <div class="blog-image">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/featured-img.jpg"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-details">
    <h3>Post Title Here</h3>
    <ul class="blog-meta">
      <li>Date</li>               
      <li>Author</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="blog-excerpt">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yH4zLmi_6n0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>                   
  </div>
```

and i used the following js

```
  function iframe_posts() {
    var video_url = $(".blog-details").find("iframe").attr("src");
    $(".blog-image").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + video_url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  }
}

iframe_posts();
```

By this code Image replacing with iframe but same iframe showing in every "blog-post". I want to show the parent video only for each  "blog-post". Suppose i have 2 blog-post with 2 different iframe. Now i want to show the iframe in
     
are

Anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with individual instances by looping over repeating elements

Can do this numerous ways but I would start at the top level repeating containers ... `class=blog-post`

```
$('.blog-post').each(function(){
   // `this` is current instance of `blog-post`
   var $post = $(this);
   // use `find()` to look inside this `$post` instance
   var video_url = $post.find('iframe').attr('src');
   $post.find('.blog-image').html('....');    
});
```

Comment: var wrapper = $(this);
var embed_url = wrapper.find("iframe").attr("src");

By using that code i did select iframe. But how could i select first firame from that blog-excerpt area? If user add multiple iframe then i want to show first first in that blog-image area.. so i need to find first iframe by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function iframe_posts() {
  var video_url = $(".blog-details").find("iframe").attr("src");
  $(".blog-excerpt").hide();
  $(".blog-image").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + video_url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
```

Comment: will still all be the same. `$(".blog-details").find("iframe").attr("src")` can only return one value...and will be from first selector match but will get applied to every `$(".blog-image")` with same url

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".blog-post").each(function(){
var wrapper = $(this);
var video_url = wrapper.find("iframe").attr("src");
 var iframe_content = ('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + video_url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
 var video_div =  wrapper.find(".blog-image")
 video_div.each(function(){
          video_div.html(iframe_content);
 });
```

});

This code resolved my problem..